# How To Choose Randomly Two Set Numbers?

Tags: random, xcode5

I created two integers and I want the code to choose randomly one of the integers. How can i do it? I'm doing it in Sprite Kit to choose the X direction of my sprite.

Comment: Have you tried researching at all? I'm sure this has been answer, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: I didn't find anything

Comment: I'm not sure if you can work off of this? http://www.raywenderlich.com/49502/procedural-level-generation-in-games-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without getting into arrays, this simplest solution is to do something like this (don't forget to put in values for `<some number>`). You can also put in any other code in the conditionals as well.

```
int random = arc4random% 9;
int myValue;
if (random >= 5) {
   myValue = <some number>;
} else {
   myValue = <some number>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I can't make it work. I can't put negative number in one of the <some number> and I don't know where to put the that code. I'm not so good at programming. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you put the negative in? You should do this like: myValue = -1;

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. That's not the problem. The problem is that if it is "random >= 4", myValue will be always the value in the "if" statement. If it is "random >= 5", myValue will be always the value in the "else" statement.

Comment: OK, I solved the problem. I must use rand() and not arc4random. Now it's ok. Thank you!